# Blazor: How to use ASP.NET Identity with non SQL Server store?

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side

I'd like to use Blazor Server with ASP.NET Identity. But I need to use PostgreSQL as a User/Roles Store because it is in AWS.
How to replace default Login/Logoff with PostgreSQL?

Comment: https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/docs/Identity-3-Tutorial.html

Comment: Add a dependency on `Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL` and refer to https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/

Comment: It is ok, but I do not want to use EF with migrations etc. I'd like to create tables manually/

Comment: @ZedZip did you ever find a solution to this? Looking into ASP.Net with my own backend db solution (postgresql) but am not interested in using EF or any other abstraction above raw sql

Comment: @user4779 yes, I have made it with postgresql without EF

Comment: @ZedZip any tips to learning this? All I can find are sporadic examples that never paint the full picture, and when combining different examples together they do things differently or from different .NET versions

Comment: @user4779 It was some time ago. I'll check it .  If you want you can send me email to continue this discussion

Comment: Hey @user4779  , check this https://github.com/ZedZipDev/AspNetCore.Identity.PostgreSQL